# Exception: "time interval must be greater than 0" while setting up notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm still getting this error even when I put a condition on my interval value. here is my code.

```
    func setupNotification(){
    
    let currentDate = Date()
    let interval = dateSelected?.timeIntervalSince(currentDate)
    if !(interval!.isZero){
    let notifcation = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notifcation.title = "Task Reminder"
    notifcation.subtitle = taskTextField.text ?? "Empty"
    notifcation.badge = 1

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval!, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "taskReminder", content: notifcation, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint -3 is not zero,  it it isn't greater than zero either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the time interval must be *greater than zero*.  You are only checking for zero, not *less than zero*. i.e. a negative value.

`timeIntervalSince()` returns the time that has elapsed *since* the specified date.  For a date that hasn't occurred yet, the time interval is a negative value.  E.g. The time interval *since* 20 seconds from now is -20 seconds.

```
func setupNotification(){
    guard let selectedDate = dateSelected else {
        return
    }

    let interval = -selectedDate.timeIntervalSinceNow()

    guard interval > 0 else {
        return
    }

    let notifcation = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notifcation.title = "Task Reminder"
    notifcation.subtitle = taskTextField.text ?? "Empty"
    notifcation.badge = 1

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "taskReminder", content: notifcation, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error at the guard let statement "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')"

Comment: Sorry,  you were unwrapping an optional, so I copied that across, but it isn't optional in my code